# GPS serial device too slow

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi

I have gps shield serially connected to my raspberry pi that I will use as a car tracking device. The problem is that it is too slow i.e. the gps module only sends gps data to raspberry after 2 minutes after a request. Are there any other simpler alternatives of detecting if a car starts moving other than using GPS device?

Comment: Maybe http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/ and https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio can be useful.

Comment: _Are there any other simpler alternatives of detecting if a car starts moving other than using GPS device?_  Look out the window?  8-)

Comment: Accelerometers - there are several modules for the arduino which measure acceleration in 2 axis. See https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/80

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your gps earlier...seriously.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix

The time to first fix can take up to almost 15 minutes from a cold, dead start.

Obviously you have not just taken the gps out of the drawer where it has been for the last 6 months and the time to first fix will be shorter.

If you want/need a shorter warm up then you'll have to leave it on or in standby.